# Scraping webpage sentences beginning with certain word

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I am scraping a webpage with BeautifulSoup and python and want to grab every sentence on the page that starts with "Text Start:", as shown in the code below. Each sentence also ends with a comma followed by a date in the form month-day (below it is 5-4) There are a lot of these instances, so I'd like to run through the page and return each sentence that begins with "Text Start:".

I've been trying to do this with the BeautifulSoup package, but have been having trouble. I thought that I should use regular expressions so I've been trying that, but haven't really gotten anywhere yet.

```
<div class="class">
<div class="time">
<span class="date">07/02/13</span>
<span class="sep">|</span>
<span class="duration">02:15</span>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
Text Start: This text changes each time, 5-4
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [regular expression](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-regular-expression) to match [specific text contents](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-text-argument):

```
import re

soup.find_all(text=re.compile('^\s*Text Start:.*'))
```

Demo:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('''\
... <div class="class">
... <div class="time">
... <span class="date">07/02/13</span>
... <span class="sep">|</span>
... <span class="duration">02:15</span>
... <div class="clear"></div>
... </div>
... Text Start: This text changes each time, 5-4
... </div>
... ''')
>>> import re
>>> soup.find_all(text=re.compile('^\s*Text Start:.*'))
[u'\nText Start: This text changes each time, 5-4\n']
```

Comment: As much as I'd love to continue [beating you](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/beautifulsoup/topusers), +1 for figuring it out before I could type `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use BeautifulSoup for such a simple task. It's much slower than using directly a regex.

Do `re.findall('^\s*Text Start:.*',page)`.

When scraping a webpage, I find useful to know the content of the page very precisely. 
Personnaly, I do this:

```
from httplib import HTTPConnection

hypr = HTTPConnection(host='stackoverflow.com',
                      timeout = 3)
rekete = ('/questions/17503336/'
          'scraping-webpage-sentences-'
          'beginning-with-certain-word')

hypr.request('GET',rekete)
page = hypr.getresponse().read()


print '\n'.join('%d %r' % (i,line)
                for i,line in enumerate(page.splitlines(True)))
```

the displaying is

```
0 '<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n'
1 '<html>\r\n'
2 '<head>\r\n'
3 '        \r\n'
4 '    <title>python - Scraping webpage sentences beginning with certain word - Stack Overflow</title>\r\n'
5 '    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico">\r\n'
6 '    <link rel="apple-touch-icon image_src" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png">\r\n'
7 '    <link rel="search" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" title="Stack Overflow" href="/opensearch.xml">\r\n'
8 '    \r\n'
9 '    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>\r\n'
10 '    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/js/stub.js?v=d2c9bad99c24"></script>\r\n'
11 '    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css?v=2079d4ae31a4">\r\n'
12 '    \r\n'
13 '    <link rel="canonical" href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17503336/scraping-webpage-sentences-beginning-with-certain-word">\r\n'
14 '    <link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" title="Feed for question \'Scraping webpage sentences beginning with certain word\'" href="/feeds/question/17503336">\r\n'
15 '    <script type="text/javascript">\r\n'
16 '        \r\n'
17 '        StackExchange.ready(function () {\r\n'
18 '            StackExchange.using("postValidation", function () {\r\n'
19 "                StackExchange.postValidation.initOnBlurAndSubmit($('#post-form'), 2, 'answer');\r\n"
20 '            });\r\n'
21 '\r\n'
22 '            \r\n'
23 "            StackExchange.question.init({showAnswerHelp:true,totalCommentCount:0,shownCommentCount:0,highlightColor:'#F4A83D',backgroundColor:'#FFF',questionId:17503336});\r\n"
24 '\r\n'
25 '            styleCode();\r\n'
26 '\r\n'
27 "                StackExchange.realtime.subscribeToQuestion('1', '17503336');\r\n"
28 '            \r\n'
29 '                    });\r\n'
30 '    </script>\r\n'
31 '\r\n'

etc etc
```